# Adding Data to JSON table onClick

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I can't figure out how to get my data to post via onSubmit() in FormComponent so that it appears in my table you see in screenshot from UsersComponent
I'm still new at this, but I feel I'm pretty close.
Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong.
OnSubmit is currently throwing following error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

[image]
FormComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../users.service';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]

})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  private _user;
constructor(private _userService: UserService){


}
onSubmit(){

this._userService.addUser()
.subscribe(res => {
this._user=res;

})
}



}
```

UserService

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService{
constructor(private _http:Http){


}
getUsers(){
return this._http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
.map(res=>res.json());

}
addUser(post){
return this._http.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", JSON.stringify(post))
.map(res=> res.json());



}
}
```

form.component.html (Pretty confident this part is correct)

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(f.value)">

<h2>User</h2>

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input ngModel id="name" #name="ngModel" name="name" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="name.touched && name.errors">
<div *ngIf="name.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>


<label for="email">Email</label>
<input ngModel id="email" #email="ngModel" name="email" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="email.touched && email.errors">
<div *ngIf="email.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="email.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input ngModel id="phone" #phone="ngModel" name="phone" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="phone.touched && phone.errors">
<div *ngIf="phone.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="phone.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>

<h2>Address</h2>

<label for="street">Street</label>
<input ngModel id="street" #street="ngModel" name="street" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="street.touched && street.errors">
<div *ngIf="street.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="street.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>


<label for="suite">Suite</label>
<input ngModel id="suite" #suite="ngModel" name="suite" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="suite.touched && suite.errors">
<div *ngIf="suite.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="suite.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>

<label for="city">City</label>
<input ngModel id="city" #city="ngModel" name="city" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="city.touched && city.errors">
<div *ngIf="city.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="city.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>


<label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
<input ngModel id="zipcode" #zip="ngModel" name="zipcode" required minLength="3" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="zip.touched && zip.errors">
<div *ngIf="zip.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
<div *ngIf="zip.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">Minlength is 3</div>

</div>


<button type="submit" [disabled] ="!f.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

Form: {{f.value | json}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your on submit you invoke `addUser` without params:

```
 this._userService.addUser()
```

While in your service it is defined to accept a `post` param. Either remove it from the method or supply it in the invocation.

Note that you `post` might fail because it requires that you set the proper headers